# SwiftyJSON keeps returning empty objects

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am new to [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON), and I'm having some trouble with it. I can get it to return the entire JSON file as a string, but the moment I try to parse it, I keep getting empty variables back, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the formatting of my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "entryID": 1,
        "from": "String",
        "to": "String",
        "value": "String"
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And this is roughly what I want to do with it (in quite inelegant code, I do apologise, I'm new to Swift):

```
for entry: JSON in indexJSON.arrayValue {

    var vEntryID: Int
    var vFrom: String
    var vTo: String
    var vValue: String
    for (dictKey: String, dictVal: JSON) in entry.dictionaryValue {
        if(dictKey=="entryID") {vEntryID = dictVal.intValue}
        if(dictKey=="from") {vFrom = dictVal.stringValue}
        if(dictKey=="to") {vTo = dictVal.stringValue}
        if(dictKey=="value") {vValue = dictVal.stringValue}
    }

    someSwiftObject[vEntryID]["from"] = vFrom
    someSwiftObject[vEntryID]["to"] = vTo
    someSwiftObject[vEntryID]["value"] = vValue
}
```

However, this block never executes at all, because indexJSON.arrayValue is always empty.

When I try to run the following, it correctly prints the complete file contents to the console:

```
let indexJSON = JSON(content!)
println(indexJSON.stringValue)
```

But when I try to go deeper, to fetch any element, it returns nothing:

```
if(indexJSON.arrayValue.isEmpty==true) {println("indexJSON.arrayValue is Empty")}
if(indexJSON[0].arrayValue.isEmpty==true) {println("indexJSON[0].arrayValue is Empty")}
if(indexJSON[0].dictionaryValue.isEmpty==true) {println("indexJSON[0].dictionaryValue is Empty")}
if(indexJSON[0]["entryID"]==nil) {println("indexJSON[0][\"entryID\"].stringValue is Empty")}
```

Output:

```
indexJSON.arrayValue is Empty
indexJSON[0].arrayValue is Empty
indexJSON[0].dictionaryValue is Empty
indexJSON[0]["entryID"].stringValue is Empty
```

I'd be grateful for any help! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am disappointed with Swifty, it is not the miraculous thing that is advertised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked SwiftyJSON source code and I think I know where the problem is.

I suppose that you are using String to initialize the JSON object like this

```
let s = "{\"entryID\": 1,\"from\": \"String\",\"to\": \"String\",\"value\": \"String\"}"
let j = JSON(s)
```

In this case the JSON object is actuall given a type "String", not Array. That's why it's not iterable and its arrayValue is empty.

To do what you want to do, you need to initialize it with an Array object:

```
let arr = [
        [
            "entryID":1,
            "from":"String",
            "to":"String",
            "value":"String",
        ]
]

let j2 = JSON(arr)
```

Now j2 is an array JSON object and iterable.

SwiftyJSON can only be initialized with NSData and object. So if you want  to initialize it with a String you need to do this:

```
if let data = s.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let j = JSON(data:data)
    println(j)
}
```

Comment: Aha! That seems really likely, I'm using this code to read the JSON: "`let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("entries", ofType: "json"); let content = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil); let json = JSON(content!)`". How would I load a file as a JSON object in a way that would make it iterable?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, make sure the format of your json string is correct. in your question, your json string is a array, just format the string like this(the content is from my code):

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"name\": \"hangge\", \"age\": 100, \"phones\": [{\"name\": \"公司\",\"number\": \"123456\"}, {\"name\": \"家庭\",\"number\": \"001\"}]}, {\"name\": \"big boss\",\"age\": 1,\"phones\": [{ \"name\": \"公司\",\"number\": \"111111\"}]}]"
```

then you can use SwityJson to get the array object, like this:

```
let strData = jsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
let json = JSON(data: strData!)
for object in json.arrayValue {
    let name = object["name"].string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON#loop

You are iterating it incorrectly. You should be iterating over the array with a for loop like this:

```
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That never fires for me for some reason.